# Реюзать cipher.Block

Tags: golang

При изучение golang возник вопрос. Можно ли повторно использовать для оптимизации `cipher.Block` и `cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(c, commonIV):`

```
func encryptData(data []byte, key []byte, commonIV []byte) ([]byte, error) {
c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(c, commonIV)
ciphertext := make([]byte, len(data))
cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, data)
return ciphertext, nil
```

}

То есть один раз создать :

```
c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(c, commonIV)
```

и подавать только `ciphertext`. И можно ли такой код шарить между горутинами (трэд сэйф)?

Answer (score 1):

cipher.Block - это interface, а в данном конкретном случае он реализован как

```
type aesCipher struct {
    enc []uint32
    dec []uint32
}
```

cipher.NewCFBEncrypter - это interface, реализован

```
type cfb struct {
    b       Block
    next    []byte
    out     []byte
    outUsed int

    decrypt bool
}
```

И то и другое содержит буферы типа slice, поэтому даже при передаче по значению у всех копий они будут указывать на одну память, а значит они не тред сейф.

Бегло поглядел на реализацию, и из-за того что блочным шифром шифруется поток данных, этот поток бьется на блоки нужного размера и шифруется, а в качестве commonIV для следующего блока выступает результат шифрования предыдущего, который и сохраняется в этих буферах. Так что переиспользовать их нельзя, иначе при попеременном вызове из разных мест они будут использовать "чужой" шифр, оставшийся в результате работы предыдущего вызова XORKeyStream.